# Wordpress.com Like Button

Tags: plugins

Is there a plugin out there similar to wordpress.com like button?
http://en.support.wordpress.com/likes/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is. Please check out [Gravatar Like](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/gravatar-like/).